# Box Class Program Java

Tags: java, class

Hello i want to make a program that can store key-value and every user add item with same key, the value is the sum of previous value + new value.
It's look like dictionary but i need to make it into a class.

```
Box box = new Box()

box.addItem("shoes", 1)
box.addItem("shoes", 3)
box.addItem("jacket", 2)

box.viewAllItem()
```

Output

```
--> shoes (4)
    jacket (2)
```

I'm a bit lost how to define the class...

Comment: Can you show what you have got so far? Right now, you already know the methods to define and their parameters.

Comment: E.g. use a `Map<String, Integer>`, to get more information / help / hints you need to provide more code / demonstrate what you tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: i'm stuck in the part `Box box = new Box()`, i dont know how to make the class of Box, i know i can use `Map<String, Integer> box = new Map<String, Integer>` but i got confused at defining it into `Box` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain insertion order you can use a **[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)**:

**Box.java:**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Box {
    private final Map<String, Integer> items;

    public Box() {
        this.items = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    public void addItem(String name, int quantity) {
        this.items.put(name, this.items.getOrDefault(name, 0) + quantity);
    }

    public void viewAllItems() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : this.items.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%d)%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();
        box.addItem("shoes", 1);
        box.addItem("shoes", 3);
        box.addItem("jacket", 2);
        box.viewAllItems();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
shoes (4)
jacket (2)
```

Comment: Thank you, now i understand how this work

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Comment: can i ask you one more question? how to run a unit testing with this void methods? i tried to search about it but didn't get the answer.

Comment: If you use IntelliJ then you can just right-click anywhere in Box.java and click generate Test (choose JUnit5), it should be easy enough to figure out.

Comment: For the actual UnitTest logic ask another question. (I won't answer but someone else should).